# field array type in entity for form choice type field symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to create a UserForm for create user in my system backend.
I use a entity with a 'role' field as type array
I want use a select choice field type Form with that entity field.
I use a transformer class system for convert data between Entity and form.

but I turn around in my head and nothing run correctly.

When I use options 'multiple' of choice type, my field display correctly but I don't want to display and select multiple value for this field.

I have `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` error
or
I have `ContextErrorException: Notice: Array to string conversion`

Here few essential code :

UserForm class

```
    $builder->add($builder->create('roles', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'I am:',
    'mapped' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'choices' => array(
        'ROLE_NORMAL' => 'Standard',
        'ROLE_VIP' => 'VIP',
    )
))->addModelTransformer($transformer));
```

transformer Class

```
class StringToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($array)
    {
        return $array[0];
    }

    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        return array($string);
    }
}
```

controller method

```
$user = new User(); //init entity
$form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($form);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
}
```

entity part

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
 */
protected $roles;

public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}
public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
    return $this;
}
```

My field roles entity must be a array for run correctly the security component Symfony

can you help me to understand why this field form refuse to display ?

I already readed others questions in same issue but there is anything that I don't understand because nothing help me to resolve my problem.

If you can help me with MY particular context...

Thank for support

Comment: If you do not want to be able to select multiple choices, why is your *role* property of type array?

Comment: because security symfony component integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because security symfony component integration

If you only need the *"getRoles"* method because of the interface you are implementing, it is simpler (and cleaner) to do the following:

- Change the entities field again to `role` with type `string`
- Rename your getter and setter to *getRole() and setRole()*
- and add a *getRoles* method like this:

  ```
  public function getRoles()
  {
      return array($this->role);
  }
  ```
- In your form type, change the field name to *"role"* and `'multiple' => false`
- Remove your model transformer

This should be the solution ;)

Comment: I don't understand why did you create a getRoles function. getRole run correctly after modified my field ?

Comment: If you are using your own User class for Symfony's security system (see [its documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database)) you have to implement the [`UserInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html), which requires the `getRoles` function to return an array with all roles ;)

Comment: It's strange that user can run correclty without implement a part of  UserInterface but exactly my new getRole() function is not a implementation of UserInterface.

Comment: hmm... but, as far as I know, you won't be able to log in, without implementing the `UserInterface`.

Comment: 4/4 implementing methods ok, 3/4 implementing methods ok but for 2/4 or 1/4 that is the most important question I think.